# Access Form Random Boxes with Dashed Lines

Tags: ms-access

After any handful of events, these random square boxes with dashed lines appear all over my application's forms. I can't figure out why or how they are being generated. Is there some type of workaround for this issue? It doesn't seem code or design related.

[image]

Comment: Are you changing the `ScreenUpdating` property?

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug in Access 2010 (and 2007?). You have a button on your form that has an **image** on it, with the size of the dashed rectangle.

The rectangle appears once the button has had the focus, and it won't go away. :(

Your database was probably migrated from Access 2003?

See [here](http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/button-outline-bug-t1999182.html) or [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/baac03d0-bdfc-4864-99b6-69c8362b491d/access-2010-dotted-line-appearing-in-form-footer-after-command-button-click) or [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/237990ce-3579-4d8f-a6b6-9c5643b57f7f/solved-access-2010-bug-or-feature-buttons-with-an-image-have-issues-with-the-focus-frame).

A possible solution from the second link:

> Set the 'Picture Property Storage Format' property in Options\Current Database to 'Preserve source image format'. Try setting that property as well as resetting the picture property in the control.

I must try this sometimes, too. It's rather annoying.

Or if you are not really attached to the image, changing the button to text-only will be the easiest fix.